# How would I increase DNS resolution timeout in a Python script?

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, dns, connection-timeout

The server that runs my Python code which get some data off of a website has to jump through so many hoops just to get to the DNS server that the latency gets to the point where it times out the DNS resolution (this is out of my control). Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

So I am trying to do some exception handling and try to ensure that it works.

Goal:

1. Increase the DNS timeout. I am unsure of a good time but let's go with 30 seconds.
2. Try to resolve the website 5 times, if it resolves, proceed to scrape the website. If it doesn't, keep trying until the 5 attempts are up.

Here is the code using google.com as an example.

```
import socket
import http.client

#Confirm that DNS resolution is successful.
def dns_lookup(host):
    try:
        socket.getaddrinfo(host, 80)
    except socket.gaierror:
        return "DNS resolution to the host failed."
    return True

#Scrape the targeted website.
def request_website_data():
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("google.com")
    conn.request("GET", "/")
    res = conn.getresponse()
    if (res.status == 200):
        print("Connection to the website worked! Do some more stuff...")
    else:
        print("Connection to the website did not work. Terminating.")

#Attempt DNS resolution 5 times, if it succeeds then immediately request the website and break the loop.
for x in range(5):
    dns_resolution = dns_lookup('google.com')

    if dns_resolution == True:
        request_website_data()
        break
    else:
        print(dns_resolution)
```

I am looking through the socket library [socket.settimeout(value)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) and I am unsure if that's what I'm looking for. What would I insert into my code to have a more forgiving and longer DNS resolution time?

Thank you.

Comment: 30 seconds for DNS resolution is really really too long, I mean it is more a sign of a problem elsewhere. If you want tighter control on your DNS needs anyway, use the DNS python library. It is a very good one and will allow you to both select which nameservers you query, TCP or UDP, and the timeouts.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Let's just say that the place I work it has insane bureaucratic oversight and forces so many checks that it bogs everything down AND they restrict my available Python library to the most barebone essentials. It's so frustrating... I'm looking for a way to just increase the DNS resolution time in the script itself without use of external third party libraries or reducing the latency. I don't even know if what I'm asking for is even feasible to be honest.

Comment: System level changes for timeouts can be set through `/etc/resolv.conf` for example but I suspect changes there will be met with the same set of stupid restrictions you describe having placed upon you. At some point, I guess, it just remains for you to explain you can not do your job in the constraints given, so either the constraints need to change or the goal...

Comment: And no `socket.settimeout` should be unrelated to your DNS problems. It doesn't cost anything to try, but don't have a lot of hope.